# How to avoid these kind of virus -- for a file such as happy cat.rmvb but is an exe file?

Tags: windows-7, virus

I almost never caught any virus on the computer, but today I just saw a virus (I am using Windows 7):

```
happy cat.rmvb
```

(just a sample file name).  Seems innocent, isn't it?   But the icon is very suspicious, because I set up Win7 to use VLC to open `.rmvb` files, but the icon is a blue play button, so I right click on the file and look at the properties, and it says "Application".

So for the viewers of this page who wants to have a little fun to figure out why that is, stop reading here, and think how that was achieved?

---

So it turns out the file is named `happy cat.rmvb  [150 spaces].exe`   So the `.rmvb` is not really the extension.  The real extension is `.exe` but it is hidden to the far right of the name.  Oh well, I almost open it and click "OK to open" because I usually is not so afraid of `.rmvb` files -- or, it could have been `.txt` which have made me even less suspicious.

So my question is, how to avoid this kind of virus?  I don't want to constantly pay for anti-virus software, and also, not all virus program can catch all virus (it may catch 95% or 99% but not all).  If that simple `.exe` is merely simple lines of program to wipe out the whole C: drive or D: drive, there is really no way to prevent it, especially it seems innocent enough for me to approve to open it.

So the question is: how to avoid this kind of virus file, as it is really insidious.

Answer (score 3):

Click start then search for Folder Options and uncheck Hide extensions for known file types

[image: Folder Options]

Now if it has 150 spaces then three dots will be shown 
[image: ...]
The ... means the file name is long (the actual extension for the file is .dll)

Comment: I already have the "Hide extensions for known file types" unchecked.  That's not the issue.  The issue is with the "..." -- who is really careful to note that there are some "..." there really?

Comment: Make sure UAC is enabled and default is prompt for elevation for unknown publishers. This will atleast reduce the impact.